# Naming the file to current date

Tags: perl, logging

I'm very new to perl, im used to C#

I'm parsing multiple xml files for some antivirus data, multiple times each day.
I'm trying to have it name the file the current date of the month, i.e. 20190425. And while its the same name, it appends to this file, if its a new day i.e. 20190426 it creates this new file and start appending to that

I'm thinking using the log function, I could "automate" the check as it would just check if the filename exists.

open (LOG, '>> report.txt'); #Append to report.txt

Can I somehow stamp this name with the current date ? so it would be
say, 20190425-Report.txt ? And that way it would automatically create a new file "tomorrow" and start adding to it

To have the script name the file the same as the current date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module changes the standard `localtime()` function so that it returns an object representing the current time. That object has a `strftime()` method that will return that time as a string formatted using a template which you pass to the method.

```
use feature 'say';
use Time::Piece;

my $now = localtime;

say $now->strftime('%Y%m%d'); # %Y = year; %m = month; %d = date
```

You could use that in your code like this:

```
use feature 'say';
use Time::Piece;

my $now = localtime;

my $today = $now->strftime('%Y%m%d');

# Note: I've switched to the three-arg version of open()
# and a lexical filehandle. Both are considered best practice.
# I've also checked the return value from open() and killed
# the program if it fails.
open my $log_fh, '>>', "$today-Report.txt"
  or die "Cannot open $today-Report.txt: $!";
```

**Update:** In your follow-up answer, you talk about getting errors trying my code. As you suspect, these errors all stem from the rather old version of Perl you are using. Perl 5.6.0 was released in March 2000 and I should point out that it has been completely unsupported by the Perl development team for a very long time. The features that are giving you problems were all added in Perl 5.10.0 (released in December 2007). I consider version 5.10 to be the absolute minimum version to use for a reasonable modern Perl development environment. I highly recommend that you upgrade to a more recent version of Perl.

Having said that, it is (of course) possible to do this in your ancient version of Perl.

```
use POSIX 'strftime';

my $today = strftime('%Y%m%d', localtime);
print "Today is: $today\n";

my $filename = "$today-Report.txt";

# I'm not sure when modern file-opening practices
# were added to Perl, so I've reverted to using a
# really old syntax.
open LOG, ">>$filename"
  or die "Cannot open $filename: $!";
```

Comment: This is a fair answer, but you don't need `Time::Piece`: you can just `use POSIX qw(strftime);` and then do `my $filename = strftime("%Y%m%d-Report.txt", localtime());`

Comment: @TFBW: True. But I prefer to use objects when I can.

Comment: Or `perl -MTime::Piece -wE'$today = (localtime)->ymd(""); say $today'`.  @TFBW -- I, too, prefer `T::P::strftime` to POSIX. (For one, it usually turns out that there's actually more to do with dates.)

Comment: Hey dave.

I actually did try and update to I believe it was 5.23 ? But it started throwing errors. And my knowledge in Perl is really not anything to brag about.

However, your update saved me, using the two variables to store date and then date+name and writing it has worked.

I agree, production environments should always be as up to date as possible. But when its something I dont have a lot of knowledge of, I prefer to just make the changes needed and let someone with the know-how, update and correct as needed.

--------------
I'm grateful for your help, thanks a bunch!!

Comment: *I believe it was 5.23* The minor version in Perl's version number (the "23" in "5.23") is a way to see if the version is a development version or a production version. Odd minor versions (like 23) are development versions of Perl and should never be installed on a production environment. The most recent production version of Perl is 5.28.2 (which was released just a week ago).